# How can a string control be added in a form during run time?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to add a string control on a form during run time when a button is clicked.

What I have tried so far:

1. Created a form
2. Added `run`  form method
3. Added `runTimeControl_validate` form method
4. Added button on the form

The button has the following code in its clicked method:

```cs
void clicked()
{
    FormBuildDesign       design = Form.design();
    FormBuildGroupControl formBuildGroupControl;
    FormStringControl     c;
    FormControlType       fC;        
    ;

    // c = addGroup.addControl(FormControlType::String, 'RunTimeControl');

    c = ButtonGroup.addControl(fC::String, 'test');
    c.label("New control");
    formBuildGroupControl = formBuildDesign.control(addGroup.id());
}
```

I am getting error in the line `c = ButtonGroup.addControl(fC::String, 'test');`

> Error: Enumeration doesn't exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, replace `fC::String` with `FormControlType::String`.

Secondly, string controls cannot be added to button groups (`ButtonGroup` control type) - add it to a normal `Group` instead.

<strike>Thirdly, to avoid such issues as missing labels, etc., it makes sense to add `element.lock();` before adding the control and `element.unlock();` after updating its label.</strike> *- ignore this*.